# Marathon Event Question

Tags: word-choice, nouns

How can I describe the marathon event more make sense?

Assumed that I want to describe an marathon event:

```
Item: full, half.
or Category: full, half;
Or Dis: full, half;
or Group: full, half;
```

Which one is better to describe a marathon event?

BTW, I noticed that from the official London marathon website, it divided by master category, etc... not by full or half.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for a word to distinguish between the half-marathon and the full marathon while still referring to them both as "marathons", I think you should probably go with "distance":

> We're running 2 distances of marathon for this charity: a full marathon, starting at 9:00 am, and a half-marathon, starting at noon.

Answer (score 0):

a full marathon is a technically 42.195 meters; half of that is a half-marathon and you can call that a [pikermi](http://www.runnersworld.com/community/forums/runner-communities/beginners/time-between-pikermis?plckFindPostKey=Cat%3aRunner%20CommunitiesForum:608106477Discussion%3ace1a6316-0a3f-467a-a418-155b30af6667Post%3ac993abee-35d2-4c5c-a060-a27cc7b1ebc5) (named so because Pikermi is right smack at the halfway point of the original Marathon distance route. The master's category are usually for age-groupers - you can divide your race between the elites (those who run for example sub-3 hours) vs. the age groups.